# Create headerView Prototype in storyboard on UITableView and dequeue it using a "resuerIdentifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

Is it possible to create a **headerView** of table **in storyboard inside the tableView**, not in a xib and **not in a separate view element** floating around in the storyboard, I want to know if it can be done inside the tableView **just like a TableViewCell prototype**, and then dequeue it in the delegate method using a "resueIdentifier".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no opportunity to create header view in storyboard, but you can do it in code, using

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

method of **UITableViewDelegate**